# Запуск react-приложения

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, node-modules, create-react-app

Мой коллега прислал мне ссылку на сборку react-приложения на GH. Клонировал все к себе, установил node и все необходимые компоненты, но получаю только следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал помимо этого с помощью команд в терминале создать новый react проект, затем перенести файлы нашего проекта в него и с помощью команд осуществить сборку и установку всех зависимостей, но это тоже не дало никаких результатов.

Порядок команд был обычным:

```
npm init react-app test-app

cd test-app

npm start
```

После чего уже производился перенос всех файлов и затем:

```
npm i

npm start
```

Если что - у меня не build-версия приложения

Comment: попробуйте `npm run start`

Comment: @ИванИпатов К сожалению, от этого ничего не поменялось. Сейчас пробовал и `npm cache clean --force`, и удалял каталог **node_modules** вместе с **package-lock.json**, чтобы потом использовать `npm i` и `npm run start`, но вообще ничего не меняется...

Comment: никаких ошибок не выводит?

Comment: @ИванИпатов Не поверите) Попробовал клонировать репозиторий заново и сделать все то же самое - все заработало, хотя буквально каких-то два часа назад при тех же действиях ничего не получалось...

Comment: Бывает, очень даже верю.

Comment: можете написать ссылку на репозиторий, который вы клонировали с гх?

Comment: @nörbörnën А с какой целью интересуетесь ссылкой? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, отвечая на собственный вопрос, хочется сказать, что у меня все решилось как-то по-своему: проделал все заново - от клонирования репозитория до написания базовых команд из разряда `npm i` и `npm run start`. Возможно, были проблемы с самим репозиторием GH, либо сбой VS Code. Если кому-то поможет - прекрасно, если нет - попробуйте удалить каталог **node_modules** и файл **package-lock.json**, после чего прописать те же самые команды для установки зависимостей и сборки приложения - иногда тоже помогает :)